# How can parameters be passed to the root navigation page in Ionic Core when using routing?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

**Overview**

In Ionic Framework, parameters can be passed to pages using the [`push` function in an `ion-nav` component](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/nav) and parameters can be passed to the root page using the `rootPage` parameter. The following code shows how this can be done:

```
// The navigation element
const nav = document.querySelector('ion-nav');

class NewPage extends HTMLElement {
  async connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = `
      <ion-header class='gallery-page' translucent>
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-back-button />
          </ion-buttons>
          
          <ion-title>Root Page</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>

      <ion-content fullscreen class="ion-padding">
       a: ${this.a}, b: ${this.b}
       
       <br />
       <ion-button>New Page</ion-button>
      </ion-content>
    `;
    
    const btn = this.querySelector('ion-button');
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.push('new-page', { a: this.a + 1, b: this.b + 1});
    })
  }
}
customElements.define('new-page', NewPage);

nav.rootParams = { a: 1, b: 2 };

/*
<!-- original body -->
<body>
  <ion-nav root='new-page'></ion-nav>
</body>
*/
```

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fL7rdvjp/1/) is a working example of the code.

**Problem**

If an `ion-router` element is used to determine what page should be displayed as the root page (instead of the `ion-nav` `root` attribute), then `rootParam` is ignored.

```
/*
<!-- modified body -->
<body>
<ion-router>
  <ion-route url='/' component='new-page'></ion-route>
</ion-router>
<ion-nav></ion-nav>
</body>
*/
```

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fL7rdvjp/2/) is an example of the modified code.

**Question**

Using Ionic with JavaScript (not Angular, React, or Vue), how can variables be properly passed to the root page when `ion-router` is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my problem was accepted as [a bug for the project on Github](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/24310), the workaround that I originally posted in the question is the solution.

**Preferred Workaround**

The `window` or `document` global objects can be used to store variables, which can be accessed by HTMLElement classes.

**Alternative Workaround**

Variables can be passed to modules using an initializtion function, but importing and calling the `initialize` function becomes a precondition. This requires creating and calling `initialize` functions in every module containing an HTMLElement which might be the root page.

```
// Module initialization code example
let a;
export function initialize(_a) {
  _a = a;
}
```